# Error: Call to a member function setPageSize() on null

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, admin-panel, product-grid

I want to override admin side product grid collection, When Override then it's showing below error

```
Error: Call to a member function setPageSize() on null in /var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/DataProvider.php:235 Stack trace: #0
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Paging.php(88): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider->setLimit() #1
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(164): Magento\Ui\Component\Paging->prepare() #2 /var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(161): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() #3
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(161): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() #4 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(142): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->prepareComponent() #5 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php(103): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent() #6 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php(93): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process() #7 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(352): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() #8 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(32): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() #9 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(129): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() #10 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() #11 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(65): Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() #12 
/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(259): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() #13
```

[image]

Below code I have used

**FIle**

```
app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml
```

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <dataSource name="driver_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\DriverDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">driver_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="addField" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">999</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="es" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
</listing>
```

**File**

app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/Ui/DataProvider/DriverDataProvider.php

**Code**

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    
    namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\DataProvider;
    
    
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider;
    
    
    /**
     * Class DataProvider
     */
    class DriverDataProvider extends DataProvider
    {
    
        protected function prepareUpdateUrl()
        {
            if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
                return;
            }
            foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
                if ('*' == $paramValue) {
                    $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
                }
    
                if ($paramValue) {
                    $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                        '%s%s/%s/',
                        $this->data['config']['update_url'],
                        $paramName,
                        $paramValue
                    );
                    parent::addFilter(
                        $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code of this file /var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Paging.php(88) from line no. 80 to 95.

Comment: Here is the code https://prnt.sc/12irrk1

Comment: Please provide the code of this file /var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/DataProvider.php:235 from line 230 to 240 that code should have the function called setPageSize()

Answer (score 0):

In this file `(/var/www/html/2.4.1/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/DataProvider/DataProvider.php)`  and at `line no. 235` , there your code is trying to execute a function named as `setPageSize()`. 
So you are trying to execute this function on something whose value is `null` so you are getting this error. 
So we need to backtrace and found why the before steps are having `null` and not having the appropriate values, once your variable(may be object of a class) will have some correct value then that variable will have the power to execute the function 'setPageSize()'.

Comment: In line 235 setPageSize function, param coming when I make it echo, it's not showing blank

Comment: Try to find out the type of variable, type is also important, do something like - <?php
$a = 3;
echo gettype($a) . "<br>";